# Videojs youtube video not playing in an iframe in desktop Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, video.js

I'm loading a `/videojs-youtube/examples/simple.html` example page from the https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube in an iframe on a different domain. When I do this the video doesn't play and the loading indicator spins and doesn't stop. I see no javascript errors in the dev console. When I access the same file directly the video plays without any issues.

The issue occurs only in the latest desktop Chrome 72.0.3626.109. Other browsers don't seem to have it.

Here's a screen capture of how it looks like on my side:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBmre1vaLwI

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/ws8tnc13/

Iframe source: https://alxd.ru/videojs-youtube/

Page source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./video.js/dist/video-js.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <video
    id="vid1"
    class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    controls
    autoplay
    width="640" height="264"
    data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube", "html5"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ"}] }'
  >
  </video>

  <script src="./video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
  <script src="./Youtube.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use this**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/QBmre1vaLwI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Of the attributes you enable, it looks to me like autoplay is the only one that is really necessary